# knockout - set visible only one item in a list generated by json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova, knockout.js

hi it's a cordova app that use devexpress framework based on knockout i need to set visible only one item in a list

the item should correspond to the param.id or this
 id_agenzia:ko.observable(params.id),

i've tryed with jquery (setting the id "#"+$data.id_agenzia visible if == id_agenzia ) but if i integrate it doesn't work

the goal is to do something like this

if i put this line it ignores 
how is the right way to set visible only the div that corresponds to $data.id_agenzia is valid for $data.id_agenzia==id_agenzia ?
thank you for help

this is the js code with jsfiddle code added

```
self.selected_id_agenzia = ko.observable('two');
self.jsonLista = ko.observableArray([
    {id_agenzia:ko.observable('one'), nome:'N1'},
    {id_agenzia:ko.observable('two'), nome:'N2'}
  noDataLabel: noDataLabel,
```

this is the html code with jsfiddle code added

```
    <div class="list-indentation" data-bind="foreach:jsonLista" style="padding-bottom:60px;">
        <div id="$data.id_agenzia" data-bind="visible: id_agenzia()==selected_id_agenzia()">
            <div class="agency-description-box" >
                <span data-bind="text: $data.id_agenzia" class="agency-name"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: $data.nome" class="agency-name"></span>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I misunderstood what you were doing with the variables. I have made a simplified fiddle to do what I think you want. To make it work:

1. I assumed a dxList was more or less like a foreach
2. I changed the name of the outer id_agenzia to selected_id_agenzia, as I was not able to get the comparison to work using $data and $root to distinguish them
3. I made both items ko.observables, and used the function call on each in the comparison

   ```
   </div>
   ```

The code is all at the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/3ktq4b9s/

Comment: thank you, if i add the function call it goes in loop, maybe the espression is not well written, i don't know, if i use this data-bind="visible: $data.id_agenzia==id_agenzia" it doesn't give error or loop  but it doesn't work, i don't know what's wrong

Comment: I have completely replaced my answer

Comment: i've understood your code even i'm newbie with knockout, i saw it working on jsfiddle but i don't understand why it goes in loop this is the complete code could you help me to understand why thank you

Comment: i've replaced the code in the question, what's wrong? thank you for help

Comment: The first thing I see is that you have made jsonLista a ko.observable rather than a ko.observableArray. The foreach binding works on an observableArray. The foreach binding goes through all the values in jsonLista and the visible binding checks whether the id_agenzia member matches the selected_id_agenzia.

Comment: yes i leaved that line uncommented by mistake, but even if i clean the code it goes always in loop, knockout is new for me and i'm finding difficult to fix it, i've replace the code again, if you can find out what's wrong thank you very much

Comment: I don't know what the dxCommand and dxContent things are, but in the fiddle they caused errors in Knockout. I changed them from data-bind to data-options to stop the errors, and things run:
http://jsfiddle.net/3ktq4b9s/1/

Comment: thank you very much for your help, KnockoutJS is new for me and with your help i've learned a little more, but the problem on this app weren't my errors or my unexpertize, even if i run perfect code, it didn't work becouse the framework and some files was damaged at the purpose to not allow me to complete the app and not get paid for the work already made, i've checked all the files and find out this, infact when i've replaced the framework files with the official ones the code worked,  unfortunatly I'm not paranoid, this happens in Italy, bye